# What is the maximum value of $C$ such that $\max_I |f'(x)|\geq C\int_0^1|f(x)|dx$?

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f$ is continuously differentiable on $I=[0,1]$, and $f(0)=f(1)=0$. How could you determine the greatest $C>0$ such that
$$
\max_I |f'(x)|\geq C\int_0^1|f(x)|dx?
$$

I know that since $f$ is continuously differentiable, $f'$ is integrable, and $\int_0^1 f'(x)dx=f(1)-f(0)=0$. But I am only able to derive some useless inequalities, like
$$
\max_I|f'(x)|\geq\int_0^1|f'(x)|dx\geq\int_0^1 f'(x)dx=0.
$$

How can I relate it to the integral of $|f|$ to determine $C$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With $M= \max_I |f'(x)|$ we have $|f(x)| \le Mx$ and $|f(x)| \le M(1-x)$ on $[0, 1]$ from the mean value theorem. It follows that
$$
 |f(x)| \le g(x) = M \cdot \max(x, 1-x)
$$
on $[0, 1]$ and therefore
$$
\int_0^1 |f(x)| \, dx \le \int_0^1 g(x) \, dx = \frac M4 
$$
or
$$
 M \ge 4 \int_0^1 |f(x)| \, dx \, .
$$
To see that $C=4$ is the largest bound consider for a fixed $M > 0$ the functions
$$
f_\epsilon(x) = M \cdot \begin{cases}
x & \text {if } 0 \le x \le \frac 12 - \epsilon \\
\frac 12 - \frac \epsilon 2 - \frac{1}{2 \epsilon}(x-\frac 12)^2\, ,
& \text {if } \frac 12 - \epsilon \le x \le \frac 12 + \epsilon \, ,\\
1-x & \text{if } \frac 12 + \epsilon  \le x \le 1\, .
\end{cases}
$$
(The idea is to modify the function $g$ slightly to make it differentiable at $x=1/2$).

Show that $f_\epsilon$ is differentiable with $\max |f_\epsilon'(x)| = M$ and that $\int_0^1 |f_\epsilon(x)| \, dx$ is arbitrary close to $M/4$ for $\epsilon \to 0$.

(Of course one can assume that $M=1$ to simplify the notation.)

Comment: How can one define $f_\epsilon$ in terms of $g$ when $g$ is dependent on $f_\epsilon$ since $M$ is?

Comment: @AdelaideDokras: What I meant is: For *fixed* $M > 0$ choose functions $f_\epsilon$ which are “close to” $g = M\max(x, 1-x)$ but differentiable. This can be done in a way such that $\max |f_\epsilon'(x)| = M$ and $\int_0^1 |f_\epsilon(x)| \, dx$ is arbitrary close to $M/4$.

Comment: $g = 1/2 -|x-1/2|$, and $|x-1/2|$ can be approximated by $\sqrt{(x-1/2)^2 +\epsilon}$. It's not exactly not Martin suggested, but I guess you might that. @AdelaideDokras

Comment: @AdelaideDokras: I have made the example more explicit, hope that helps.

Comment: @MartinR with regards to my deleted answer, the question is phrased: **given any** $f$, what is the maximal $C$ such that... as opposed to what is the maximal $C$, such that for any $f$,... . So I believe I am correct in the technical sense, but its probably not what is meant, so I'll just leave it deleted....?

Comment: @CalvinKhor: That's up to you (you could also ask OP for clarification). But if $f$ is given then $C = \max_I |f'(x)| / \int_0^1|f(x)|dx$ is a fixed number, so it does not make much sense to ask for the largest $C$ for a specific $f$.

Comment: Me deleting it was me choosing what battles to fight (don't think its worth it) :)